# I have similar code to this and im wondering if there is way to make it short

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am wondering how i can make them short in my js file. i have so many code similar to this. I have repeated this if function again and again also have to repeat else function as well.The only thing is changed is Mission() Doclick() and Yesdo(). If there is way to make it short let me know thanks.

```
function Buy() {
    if (uida == '234' || uidb == '4563') {
        Mission();
    } else {
        stop();
    };
};

function Start() {
    if (uida == '234' || uidb == '4563') {
        Doclick();
    } else {
        stop();
    };
};

function ReBuy() {
    if (uida == '234' || uidb == '4563') {
        Yesdo();
    } else {
        stop();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function pointers!

```
function Uida(fn) {
    if (uida == '234' || uidb == '4563') {
        fn();
    } else {
        stop();
    };
}

function Buy() {
    Uida(Mission);
};

function Start() {
    Uida(Doclick);
};

function ReBuy() {
    Uida(Yesdo);
}
```

Of course, you'll want to rename the `Uida` function to something more descriptive :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look to make them all call one similar function and pass a `uida` paremeter, something like this:

```
// You could change the following 3 functions to have ternary statements
// eg: if ( uidaCheck() ) ? Function() : stop();
//
function Buy() {
    if ( uidaCheck() ) {
        Mission();
    } else {
        stop();
    }
}

function Start() {
    if ( uidaCheck() ) {
        Doclick();
    } else {
        stop();
    }
}

function ReBuy() {
    if ( uidaCheck() ) {
        Yesdo();
    } else {
        stop();
    }
}

function uidaCheck() {
    // uida assumed to be globally accessible var
    //
    if ( ( uida == '234' ) || ( uida == '4563' ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That's the theory anyway, gimme a sec and I'll see if I can tidy it up a bit. ([ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation))

Here's a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6jCc/).

Comment: Thanks alot i got an idea to fix it now :)

Comment: thanks brother yes im trying both soultion and i will see which is better for me thanks so much